# Keycloak: Implement group-based access restrictions

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I'm working on a company app written using React and Node.js, and we're wanting to upgrade from Keycloak version 11 to 23. I'm currently working on the app in a local development environment.

We have a main realm (we'll call it main-realm) with the following clients:

- account
- account-console
- admin-cli
- broker
- react-client
- realm-management
- security-admin-console

[image]

For the 'react-client' client, we have the following fields set:

- Valid redirect URIs: http://localhost:*
- Web origins: http://localhost:*
- Client authentication: On
- Authorization: On
- Authentication flow: Standard flow, Direct access grants

[image]

I have access to the setup docs we used for the old version of the app running on Keycloak 11. Here's the steps outlined in those docs regarding setting up groups and admin users:

> Rules and Groups Setup
>
> Groups and Users - Keycloak
> Each user will be assigned to group(s) that grants them access to their applications. The group(s) that users belong to determines which applications they can access once they login to the Cloudflare landing page. Groups are created within Keycloak. Below are steps to create a group in keycloak.
>
> Create a Group
>
> Go to the Keycloak admin console and login using your credentials. If you have not logged into keycloak before, your username is your company email address and the password is ChangeMe1234$. Once you login for the first time you will be prompted to create a new password.

[image]

> Under the main-realm realm, go to groups. If you are in the main-realm realm you will see main-realm with a dropdown in the top left. If you are not in the main-realm realm, select the drop down then select main-realm.
>
> Select new, then name the group the same name you used for the tunnel, then click save.
>
> Click on the attribute tab for the group
>
> Under key, put group0. For value, put the name of the group. Click add, then click save. ***ENSURE THAT YOU ARE USING THE SAME NAME FOR THE GROUP AND TUNNEL***
>
> When adding the attribute, if you have multiple groups managed by the same customer, use group0 for the attribute key on the first group, then group1 for the attribute key on the second group, then group2 on the third group and so on.
>
> Keycloak - Permissions
>
> We will be providing the lead of each group with low level admin credentials to be able to manage the users of their group(s) and their group(s) only. In order to limit their permissions within the keycloak console, we need to create permissions for their group and give the user some admin role mappings.
>
> Adding an Admin User
>
> Go to users, select add user. Create a username for the admin (first letter of first name and last name, EX. JDoe), and enter their email, first name and last name. Under groups, search for the group that you created for this admin. Click save.
>
> If you have created multiple groups for one admin to manage, add the admin to each group that they will manage.
>
> Click on the credentials tab under the user. Change the password for the user to ChangeMe1234$. Make sure that the temporary check box is not selected. Click reset password. We will set a temporary password for the user to user later.
>
> Click on the role mappings tab. Under client roles, select realm-management.
>
> Under available roles, find query-groups and query-users. Add these roles to the user by clicking add selected.

[image]

> Click on groups on the left-hand menu. Double click the group you are creating an admin user for.
>
> At the end of the URL, add /permissions. This will take you to the permissions page.

[image]

> Enable permissions on the group.
>
> Click view-members.
>
> Under apply policy, select the create policy drop down. Select user.

[image]

> Name the new policy -AdminViewMembers.
>
> Under users, select the admin user you created for this group.

[image]

> Click save. Then click save again on the permissions page.
>
> Go back to the permissions page for the group you created. Click manage-members.
>
> Select the create policy drop down and select users.
>
> Name the new policy -AdminManageMembers.
>
> Select the user that you created to be the admin for this group. Click save. Click save again on the permissions page.
>
> Go back to the permissions page for the group. Click manage-membership.
>
> Select the create policy dropdown and select users.
>
> Name the new policy -AdminManageMembership.
>
> Select the user that you created to be the admin for this group. Click save. Click save again on the permissions page.
>
> If you have multiple groups for this admin to manage, repeat these steps for each group that they will manage.

This setup uses group-based permissions and policies. However, this functionality has been deprecated in newer versions of Keycloak, so now I am trying to figure out how to implement the equivalent functionality in version 23.

I started asking ChatGPT how to implement this functionality, and here's the steps it outlined for me:

1. Navigate to the react-client client. Ensure the Client authorization and Authorization fields are toggled On. Also, ensure for Authentication flow that Standard flow and Direct access grants are checked.
2. Navigate to the Authorization tab
3. Create a new authorization scope. For now, I named it 'view-members' since I thought I'd test out the ability to view other members first.

[image]

4. After that, I created a policy. ChatGPT suggested creating a Javascript-based policy, but it appears that JS-based policies were deprecated in version 15. Therefore, I opted to create a group-based policy.

[image]

5. I was hoping that I could create a dynamic group-based policy, i.e. it would check which groups are contained in the user's access token and give them access to those groups only. However, when configuring a group-based policy, Keycloak enforces that at least one group is selected. Therefore, this is not a dynamic approach. Nevertheless, I proceeded by selecting the 'test' group.
6. Then, I created a resource titled 'view-members-resource'.

[image]

7. After that, I created a permission which I titled view-members-permission. In this permission, I added 'view-members' as an authorization scope and 'group-based-access' as a policy.

[image]

It's at this point that I'm stumped about how to proceed. I have a user named 'permissions_test' who is a member of the 'test' group.

[image]

The user has the following roles:

- [realm-management] query-users
- [realm-management] query-groups
- default-roles-main-realm

The 'default-roles-main-realm' is composed of the following roles:

- uma_authorization
- offline_access
- [realm-management] query-users
- [realm-management] view-users
- [account] manage-account
- [account] view-profile

Thanks for any help!